# what is last visible row in a range that contain hidden rows and hidden columns

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote below

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("tblInsurance").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count
```

to point last row of `tblInsurance` Table.

I pass `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("tblInsurance")` in method argument as:

```
General.CsvExportRange rngRange:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("tblInsurance")
```

and `CsvExportRange` method contain `rngRange.Rows.Count` line for finding last row of the range.

But when reaching the hidden row, it stops counting and returns the number of the last row before the hidden one.

when I use below:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("tblInsurance").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
```

range is selected entirely by separated boundaries around the visible area in the range.

Seems the problem is in `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count`->**count** method, which stops counting when reaching hidden row.

I was reading similar posts and web discussions but they not contain above major issue. (Counting range rows for finding last row number, when the range contains hidden rows.)

This issue is a similar one, when I try to count range columns that contain some hidden column, to -for example- reach the last one.

Comment: Unclear....do you want the last row that **contains** data or the last row that **contains visible data** ??

Comment: I want last row that **contains visible data**, so I want count of **all visible rows** are in the range. Please note that range contains some hidden rows. And I need count them for finding last visible row of the range.

Comment: `.SpecialCells`  is returning a range that contains multiple areas.  `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count` will return the number of rows in the first area of the range.

Comment: Of course the question is that. I want number of rows in all areas of the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is interesting. I never thought of this issue.
Try this:

```
Sub test()
Dim rngDB As Range, rng As Range
Dim n As Integer, c As Integer, cnt As Integer

Set rngDB = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("tblInsurance").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
c = rngDB.Columns.Count
For Each rng In rngDB
    n = n + 1
Next
cnt = n / c
MsgBox cnt
End Sub
```

If you need to know the number of last cell's row,  try this:

```
Sub test2()
Dim rngDB As Range, rng As Range
Dim n As Integer
Set rngDB = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("tblInsurance").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
  n = rngDB.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
  MsgBox "My last row number is : " & n
End Sub
```

I tested of course.

[image]

**Edit**
I understand your problem. try like this.

```
Sub test3()
Dim rngDB As Range, rng As Range
Dim n As Integer, r as Long, c as Integer
Set rngDB = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("tblInsurance").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    With rngDB
        r = .Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        C = .Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
        Set rng = Range("a1", .Cells(r, C))
    End With

  MsgBox "My last row number is : " & r
End Sub
```

Comment: False and far answer.

Comment: @MGae2M,  if you want to know lastcell row number,  I edit my code.

Comment: Unfortunately `SpecialCells` method with `xlCellTypeLastCell` enumerate  argument **not return correctly**. it return 9 number more than number of last row of range.

Comment: The problem is, when we used a cell in equal place of `Worksheet` lower than the `Row11` in your example, the `xlCellTypeLastCell` return row number higher than 11. In a `Worksheet` same as mine, may there several equal `Tables`, as I have a `Pivot Table` at the end of other `Column`s places and lower other Tables `Row`, thus cant use `xlCellTypeLastCell` property.

Comment: @MGae2M, I understand your issue. I add some code at my answer.

Comment: @, `.Find` is  S M A R T solution!

Answer (score 2):

You can use Range.end(xlup).row to find the last visible row; if a1:a100 contains data but rows A8:a100 are hidden then this code will show row 7

```
Sub lastvis()
MsgBox Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Row
End Sub
```

Or if using a table try this to find the last visible row.

```
Sub lastvis2()
MsgBox Range("tblInsurance").End(xlDown).Row
End Sub
```

Comment: This innovative answer can be extend, use of **Dy.Lee**'s (above) answer: `MsgBox givenRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).End(XlUp).Row` in special situation that end of the range is end of `Table`. But if the end is between visible table row and bellow that there were some filtered rows, that not work. So in your answer, How we can calculate `A1000`'s `1000` number?!

Comment: I cant accept your innovative answer, because the problem is in calculating `A1000`!. May given range is between Table, with some filtered (hidden) rows under and upper and between.(Of course columns)

Answer (score 0):

Sadly **.Count** does not get us much information.  Say we have only a single column, **A1-A100** and we run:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim r As Range, r2 As Range

    Set r = Range("A1:A100")
    Set r2 = r.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    MsgBox r2.Rows.Count
End Sub
```

and when run, the macro gives us ***4***.

All you know is the somewhere in the table there are 4 visible rows.  We have no idea which are the visible ones.  We also have no idea if any of these visible rows contain data or are empty.

The best we can do is to loop through the table , starting from the bottom.

When we encounter a row that is both visible and non-empty, stop and report the row number.

Comment: I want finding last row in a `Filtered Table` list. and use `.Count` property for that. So right is: {**When we encounter a last row before non-visible (filtered) -or empty row-, stop and report the row number.**} If you have idea for loop through the table from starting to bottom, please present that.

Comment: What is above answer use?

Comment: @MGae2M  I will supply some sample code for you later today

Comment: Why we cant use `.Count` property against of use `EntireRow.Hidden` in a loop through the table?

Answer (score 0):

.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) returns a multiple-area range. You can access the each area with the Range.Areas property. The [official documentation for Range.Count](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.count) gives this example:

```
Sub DisplayColumnCount() 
    Dim iAreaCount As Integer 
    Dim i As Integer

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate 
    iAreaCount = Selection.Areas.Count 
 
    If iAreaCount <= 1 Then 
        MsgBox "The selection contains " & Selection.Columns.Count & " columns." 
    Else 
        For i = 1 To iAreaCount 
            MsgBox "Area " & i & " of the selection contains " & _ 
            Selection.Areas(i).Columns.Count & " columns." 
        Next i 
    End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: Not depended main question!